# Forbidden - you don't have permission to access occurring randomly on Browser

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-403

I have my website live on C*ent Os Server Apache 2.2.15*. Developed on *PHP Codeigniter*.

I get `Forbidden error` for the 1st time as I visit the website.

But then as I refresh it goes away and the page is loaded perfectly.

This happens to random users and not for everyone.

For some the site runs smoothly without any error.

Comment: What is the code you run for session management? Do you push a code forbidden for people without sessions?

Comment: I don't send User to 403 withour session , Session starts as the web page loads.

Also I have this site live on 2 server . Which are behind load balancer. 

On one server the site is not getting 403 in access log , which on other server the access log has 403.

Comment: Do they receive a CodeIgniter 403 or a real server 403? Could you trace back from which URLs the 403s are coming? Maybe someone is sharing a link you only are able to view after login or something like that? Ps. You have to tag people otherwise they are not getting notified. I will notify @MichaelDibbets for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a configuration difference between those two servers. Make sure that both servers have exactly the same:

- Apache configuration
- PHP configuration
- folders structure and permissions

Comment: Folder Structure and presmissions are same. 

phpinfo on both server had following difference :

Server 1  `Has HTTP_PRAGMA and HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  = no-cache` , while this is not shown in Server 2.

`Server 2 has SOAP installed` ,while soap is not there on Server 1. 

SOAP is required in other websites and api which are hosted on server 2.

The error that I get occurs on Server 2.